# Windows 2012 R2 Server Core reduced/minimum RAM usage (for VMs)

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012-r2

The minimum requirement for Server 2012 is 512MB of RAM. But since server core doesn't need GUI, is it possible to run the core with **even less RAM?**

If so, what's the minimum?

*I plan on running it on a virtual machine, mostly for routing/DHCP/DNS purposes, and I want to do so by giving it as little RAM as possible as it will be run alongside other VMs.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, it will run - but it will run extremely poorly.

Server Core is a full on Windows Server install - just without the GUI.  You still get full functionality of (in your case) DHCP, DNS etc and all thats missing are the point and click elements.  Server Core is NOT a cut-down, DOS only type server.

In your case, you will be running a full Windows server with multiple roles installed and while 512MB will run, you will have poor performance - especially when performing heavy-duty taks such as sending large DNS updates to DCs etc.

Interestingly enough (and on a side note) - you can actually turn the GUI on and off as a windows feature in PowerShell using `Get-WindowsFeature *gui* | Uninstall-WindowsFeature –Restart` (and Intall-WindowsFeature)

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind this is Server Core, not command prompt only system (DOS), 512MB is even lag at sometime in lab environment. If you use that in production, 512MB ram is observably not enough.

Besides, if you really want to bypass the minimum hardware requirements during the installation, simplest way is you can install it with 512MB first then adjust the RAM setting in VM setting later.

Comment: Installation requirements is not a problem. I can supply sufficient ram during installation.